# Putting a Variable inside a Conversion Specification in C

Tags: c

I have an assignment and I was trying to figure out two ways to do one thing. I have the code here

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
    char first[10];
    int length;


  printf("what is your first name?\n");
  scanf("%s", &first);
  length = strlen(first)+3;
  printf("%d\n", length);
  printf("Hi \"%s\"\n", first);
  printf("Hi \"%20s\"\n", first);
  printf("Hi \"%-20s\"\n", first);
  printf("Hi \"%8s\"\n", first);
  return 0; 
}
```

Fairly simple overall. However, the last statement

```
printf("Hi \"%8s\"\n", first);
```

was something I wanted to do differently. The criteria for the that statement was to print it in a field 3 characters wider than the name. With my name Being Chris, I know that being 8 Characters wide accomplishes this, however, I was wondering if I could use the length variable I have created and do something like this below so that I don't have to know the length of the name ahead of time.

```
printf("Hi \"%[Length]s\"\n", first);
```

I know that doesn't work, but I think it gets the idea across.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an asterisk instead of a specific with value to indicate that the width will be specified as another parameter:

```
printf("Hi \"%*s\"\n",length,first);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Now that you mention that, I think I saw it somewhere... well thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 7):

Specify width with an additional parameter:

```
printf("Hi \"%*s\"\n", length, first);
```

(note the `*` instead of field width).

Answer (score 5):

You want:

```
printf("Hi \"%*s\"\n", length, first);
```

`*` is an optional *field width* and `length` has to be an `int` argument.